# Reload A same Component in angular 4

Tags: datatables, angular2-routing, angular4-router

[i am using Datatable to show the records of members of organization. Firstly it loads data from API but when i add new member it gives me error Datatable can not be initialized again so i want to reload that component or any other solution to this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1lWT.png)

Comment: datatable can not be initialized twice so i want to reload component not whole app or any other logic which will remove datatable and add it again

Comment: Please do not share your code as image, but as text inside your question body.